# How to Disable Chrome's New User Menu in Windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Can i get rid of this icon? I have disabled the `enable-new-avatar-menu` as well the `enable-new-profile-management` flag, but now this changes nothing (Tried on two Windows and one OS X machine).

On OS X opening Chrome from the command line

I found [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/677/556) online. Opening Chrome from the command line and passing the `--disable-new-avatar-menu` flag works on OS X, but not on windows. Is there a way to pass similar command line arguments under windows?
Ideally setting this up in a way that it gets opened that way if I click the Chrome Icon in the Taskbar?

Comment: The menu came back for me. Since they added it a year ago I've had the button disabled, but a recent update to `44.0.2403.89 m` apears to have forced enabled it back. I had to do what @ergospace said but I needed to kill Chrome with the Task Manager for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

start chrome with

```
chrome.exe --disable-new-avatar-menu
```

Comment: I already tried this. No effect at all

Comment: chrome://flags #enable-new-profile-management did not work for me but chrome.exe --disable-new-avatar-menu makes trick for me on windows 8.1